# Save WPF ViewModel current state

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF application's `ViewModel` has few properties, observableCollections etc.
How can I save their current state as file when app is closing or save clicked
Should I use `[Serializable]` implementation?

What is the best approach?

```
public class CustomerViewModel 
{
    private Customer obj = new Customer();

    public string TxtCustomerName
    {
        get { return obj.CustomerName; }
        set { obj.CustomerName = value; }
    }        

    public string TxtAmount
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(obj.Amount) ; }
        set { obj.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the best approach is depends on your requirements. You could for example serialize your class using the built-in `DataContractJsonSerializer` class without modifying the class at all:

```
CustomerViewModel vm = new CustomerViewModel();
//...

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CustomerViewModel));
    ser.WriteObject(ms, vm);
    File.WriteAllText("save.txt", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}
```

You will need to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`. Please refer to the following blog post for more information: https://www.bytefish.de/blog/enum_datacontractjsonserializer/.

A popular high-performance third-party JSON serializer is othwerwise Json.NET: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json. And there are plenty of other solutions that use various formats, whether they are text-based or binary. In complex cases you may have to write your own custom serializer.

Comment: in this case `CustomerViewModel` should have `[Serializable]` Attribute?
and can I make this `Save` inside VM?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you don't need to decorate your class with any attributes. I also showed you an example of how to "make the save". You could put this code wherever you want to.

Comment: `CustomerViewModel vm = new CustomerViewModel();` creates an empty object, but i want to save current state
therefor I've used `this` but it gives an error `was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.`

Comment: How can I return back?
Question is how to used deserialized object as ViewModel

Comment: Read the link I supplied and please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: you can write at least "please"

Comment: I thought I did; "please ask..".

Comment: Deserialization is very similar. You just use the ReadObject method as mentioned in the blog post.

Comment: Dear mm8, i know how to deserialize how should i put back ViewModel
Imagine i have `CustomerViewModel vm=Desiarlize(...)` and how shoult I use this `vm`
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard practice for persisting MVVM state.  You just need to pick a format, just like you would for any other serialization problem.  I personally am a fan of using Xaml, as it's human readable and can represent most of the types that you might be using in a WPF application.

Example code, included in a base class for your view models:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private static string RootStoragePath =>
        Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
            "YourApplication",
            "ViewState");

    protected string StateFilePath =>
       Path.Combine(RootStoragePath, this.GetType().Name + ".xaml");

    public void Save()
    {
        var fileName = StateFilePath;

        var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
        if (directoryName != null && !Directory.Exists(directoryName))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

        XamlServices.Save(fileName, this);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        var fileName = StateFilePath;

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (var file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            using (var reader = new XamlXmlReader(file))
            {
                var writer = new XamlObjectWriter(
                    reader.SchemaContext,
                    new XamlObjectWriterSettings { RootObjectInstance = this });

                using (writer)
                {
                    XamlServices.Transform(reader, writer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The saved state would look something like this:

```
<CustomerViewModel TxtAmount="3.5"
                   TxtCustomerName="Mike Strobel"
                   xmlns="clr-namespace:WpfTest;assembly=WpfTest" />
```

Note that this is a minimal example.  Ideally, your error handling on the storage operations would be more robust.  Be sure to change `RootStoragePath` to be unique to *your* application.

Comment: How can I ignore some properties
`Unable to read objects of the type 'Module+TwainImport_Plugin'.  Nested types are not supported.`

Comment: Sounds like something that should not be included.  Any properties that should not be persisted need to be annotated with `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]`.  Alternatively, you can mark it as `internal` or `protected internal` and only make the persisted properties `public`.

Comment: How does your code know which viewmodel to save? How does it know it must save CustomerViewModel?